# Xamarin Forms: Prevent Keyboard resizing the view

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

we have a WebView inside of a Grid. When I touch inside a control of my webview the Keyboard will show and resize my view. Is it possible to avoid the Keyboard from resizing or moving my view? the webview should stays where it is. the Keyboard should be lay over my webview and should not be scrollable.

Comment: try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode), or add a scrollview.

Comment: If the keyboard is covering part of the webview, how will you handle the situation where the control being typed into is hidden under the keyboard?